# How much space does a Fire Imp need to spawn in?

Tags: terraria

In Terraria, how much space is required for a fire imp to spawn/teleport? So far, I've kept my hellstone mine restrited to either 3 tiles high or 2 tiles wide, and I haven't had any trouble until I attempt to mine a large patch of hellstone. So what is the minimum required space for an imp? It must be more than 2x3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Fire Imps seem to require a target
>   space of 4 blocks high by 3 blocks
>   wide to teleport into a location.

From the [Terraria Wiki](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Fire_Imp)

Just be sure to fill in some of the hellstone you mine to keep the imps from spawning.

Comment: But don't you need to fill the area above the hell-stone and to the sides? Because if they just spawn there they can still annoy you...